# Is there an "@media" style that affects the viewport?

Tags: css, dynamic, cross-browser, media-queries, viewport

I have a website where when the screen goes above 1400px; the website no longer expands. However, I also have a floating element. the navbar is floated to the left and scales down in size with the page. However, I don't wamt it to style if the screen size gets larger.

If someone views my page above 1400px screen resolution it works and does not move. However, if someone views the website and zooms out increasing the viewport size not the screen size it stays stuck to the left hand side and distorts.

***I want a div to display:none if the screen size or the viewport size reaches a maximum size of 1400px;***

I need compatibility for modern browsers and mobile devices.

Comment: `@media all and (max-width: 1400px) {` doesn't work?

Comment: @Explosion Pills: Apparently not - I've had this happen to me before on page zoom, but I have no idea if that is by design - even though `width` and `height` are stated to apply to the viewport.

Comment: @BoltClock I think that is a Webkit bug; ostensibly it's fixed by using `em` instead of `px` (I've read that), but it didn't work for me when I tried it.

Comment: @Explosion Pills: I reproduced it on Firefox actually, so it's either not exclusive to WebKit, or something else is at play.

Comment: i was really hopeful about
    @media all and (max-width: 1400px) {

however, unfortunately it doesn't work. 

If I cant figure out it means a whole revamp.

is there a javascript/jquery script i can run?

Comment: @BoltClock I have managed a quick fix but it's still not idea, however, it keeps it inside its parent. I still have it absolute however, I have set it's max-width to 1400px; and margin's to auto. It still goes a bit messed up if zoom out too far but it keeps it bound to the content area.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this...

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 1400px){
      div {
            display:none;
    }
    }
```

Comment: This is what I have if the screen resolution results in the **window** size being +1400px this displays the div as none. However if the screen is any size and you zoom out making the **viewport** size bigger +1400px major fail!

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (min-width: 1400px) {
    body {
        background:red !important;
    }
}
```

works for me :)

EDIT: sorry missed the part about zooming the page. i'm not sure viewport is supposed to work like that?

Comment: What's with that `!important`?

Comment: that was just the test code i used to make sure it was quickly viewable as working. i missed the zooming part, though, sorry. it doesn't work on zoom.

Comment: admittedly if something doesn't work !important is the first thing i try.

viewports are not ssupposed to work like that.

ive read there is an @viewport but that it has no browser support its mainly for mobiles. which ive tested and it doesnt work.

it seems like the problem may be better suited to javascript